# Are there torrents that contain large free spatial datasets?

Tags: data

I've been having a lot of issues downloading entire datasets of SRTM or ASTER GDEM2 or similar free datasets, mainly because of poor services. Does anyone know of any torrents which contain such free datasets?

Comment: None that I know of. Which is kind of weird considering that spatial data seems to be a perfect fit for bittorrent distribution. Maybe you can start :)

Comment: Hehe, would, if i were able to download it in full first. Those web interfaces are either dreadfully unstable, or have some wird limitations :D

Comment: download managers help where resume is supported..i downloaded the Grass sample mapsets using them..

Comment: FTP is more manageable (controlling version of data), bit torrent has lots of hidden bad illegal data/viruses.

Comment: I disagree, its rather hard to add a virus into a non executable file and i was talking about data freely available. From this standpoint i agree with R.K. the torrent technology would be great for this. Can you post a ftp, where one could freely (no download quotas and similar nonsense) download one of the mentioned datasets in the question? (And that has a decent upload speed, not 60kbps)

Comment: Can you link specific sites that you have been trying to get this data from?  I tried pulling from a site that had some ASTER GDEM2 data on it and got decent speeds though I am on a T3 right now.

Comment: If you set up torrent, then I could seed it, like I do with OSM Planets with a special free-geo server with unlimited good connection. It is best if original distributor sets it up, so they follow the terms properly.

Answer (score 1):

The folks at ER Mapper used to have one at [geotorrents.org](http://torrentfreak.com/geotorrentorg-distributes-free-satellite-imagery/) but it's gone now. :(

Comment: The site is inaccessible, probably gone? Shame!